# How to reinitialize audio devices after opening Ableton Live?

Tags: ableton-live, audio

After opening Ableton, when I plug in another Audio device I have to completely restart it before Ableton recognizes the devices, is there an option to have Ableton look for new devices?

Comment: What did they answer at Ableton's support? I don't have this problem on the Mac btw. The only thing that's necessary is to click/open the dropdown sound device list after plugging in a new USB audio interface, not necessary to even close the settings/config window.

Comment: Oh, for me I have to reopen Ableton completely. I haven't asked Ableton Support, never really thought of going straight to them with the question haha. Might just go and do that later on though.

Comment: Sometimes, like maybe 1 out of 50 times, the plugged-in device doesn't appear in the list until I unplug and replug it, but I don't recall having to close Ableton for that.